# cannot be resolved to a variable - Parse.com

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve information from parse. In particular, I have added a condition where it would only return the list of users that have selected the same activity. In doing so, I unexpectedly receive the following error:

```
userActivitySelectionName cannot be resolved to a variable
```

It would essentially see which users have selected that particular activity name and return I randomly added this variable because I would like to retrieve the list of usersname who have selected that activity with the exception of the currentuser. I did not want to specificly point out a username since the list changes all the time, so was thinking of having a generic variable name such as userActivitySelectionName

Below is the entire code

```
 public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

 private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);

        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        setConversationsList();
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();


        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
       query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                    }

                    usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("username", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
           public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
               if (e == null) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                   startActivity(intent);
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Error finding that user",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have a variable named `userActivitySelectionName`. You need to create that.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to declare this variable `userActivitySelectionName`. You need to declare this variable and assign the datatype, which is going to store.

say

```
String userActivitySelectionName = null;
```

As @Suresh said, You need to make a check of `null` value before you make any operations on it like

```
if(userActivitySelectionName!=null)
query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);
```

Otherwise, you will get `NullPointerException` when you invoke methods or access properties of a `null` value.

If the value is `null`, you can set a meaningful value instead of `null` say empty string `""` for a String variable

Comment: Can you please warn about NPE as well ??

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The problem is that when I initializes it to null, the conditions seems to not apply, and hence the entire list returns, regardless if the two activity matches or not.

Comment: @user3827788 I'd like to understand why you have the variable `userActivitySelectionName` and where you initialize it. It would be appropriate to do what is needed when its value is null. It will be purely based on your context.

Comment: I do agree that the variable name useractiveselectname is not a neccecity. At first I though this issue is quite simple, but it seems to more complex than I thought in generating the list of users that are equal the same activity name within the activityname column.